# Hunchentoot handler for dynamic amount of parameters

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I want to be able to handle a form which uses a dynamic amount of form fields

e.g.

```
(form :action "/theaction"
      :method "post"
      (input :type "text" :name "firstinput") (:br)
      (dotimes (i n)
         (:input :type "text" :name (FORMAT nil "INPUT~a" i)))
      (:input :type "submit" :value "submit" :name "submit"))
```

how can I define the handler as the `&rest` is not accepted and would not allow me to access the variable names which I obviously need for further processing.

```
(define-easy-handler (theaction :uri "/theaction") (&special-rest all-params)
   (log-message* :INFO "~a" all-params))

-> "(("firstinput" . "value") ("INPUT0" . "value") ("INPUT1" . "value") ...)"
```

A possibility would be to pre-define all variables up to e.g. 100, but this would seem rather cumbersome and unintuitive.

Comment: Offhand, I wonder if if `define-easy-handler` is designed for simpler cases.  Maybe you need to use the more general form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda-list of `define-easy-handler` is just a shortcut for using lower-level calls. You can get more extensive access to parameters by using functions like like `GET-PARAMETER` and `POST-PARAMETER`. You can get an alist of all parameters by using [get-parameters*](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#get-parameters*) (or [post-parameters*](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#post-parameters*)) in the body of the handler.